# How does Ninject create controller in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, ninject-2, ninject.web.mvc

This may be stupid question, but I am looking at Ninject sources and don't see NInject registering its own controller factory. I also don't see any `IControllerFactory` class in `Ninject.Web.Mvc` assembly. Am I missing something? How does Ninject create controller and inject parameters into constructor?

Comment: It looks like my application is following that same logic. It looks like it is not registering the controller.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Lets say we are looking for "/Task/Index".
2. Ninject MVC applications use now `DefaultControllerFactory`, the same as non-Ninject applications.
3. `DefaultControllerFactory` finds type for controller (`TaskController`).
4. `DefaultControllerFactory` has internal class called `DefaultControllerActivator`. `DefaultControllerActivator` has method called `Create`, which returns controller instance. `DefaultControllerFactory` asks `DefaultControllerActivator` for `TaskController` type instance.
5. `DefaultControllerActivator.Create` uses `IDependencyResolver`. This is where `Ninject` comes in. Since `Ninject` implements its own resolver and sets it at the start of application, he gets request for `TaskController` instance.
6. The rest is easy. `Ninject` finds constructor for this type, injects parameters, returns controller instance.

Answer (score 4):

MVC3 now recommends the usage of the `IDependencyResolver` interface instead of the good old `IControllerFactory` when dealing with DI. You can look at more details of this interface [here](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2011/02/01/IDependencyResolverAspNetMvc3.aspx).

[This is the new Ninject class](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/blob/master/mvc3/src/Ninject.Web.Mvc/NinjectDependencyResolver.cs) responsible for injecting the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Since controllers are concrete types, Ninject will do self bind. Below is a snippet from `ninject.complex.com`

> Bear in mind that only concrete types can be self-bound; abstract
>   types and interfaces won't work. Also, if you request an instance of a
>   type that can be self-bound, and there are no bindings defined for the
>   type, Ninject will automatically create an implicit self-binding. It's
>   up to you whether you want to define your bindings explicitly, or let
>   Ninject figure it out.

If you do need to inject parameters into the constructor. You can create a class inherits from `INinjectModule` and do the binding there.