# Where and when do Ninject Create a Controller in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, controller, ninject

I am using the NuGet add the Ninject and Ninject.Web.Mvc reference to my project.
but i don't add  register code for the controller(with a parameter constructor) binding. but it seems the controller was created correctly, i wonder how Ninject create the controller with dependency parameter withou register the controller to the ninject.
in the Ninject.Web.Mvc, and i found the following sentense in the author (ninject) 's blog,

The controller itself will be found by Ninject even without adding a binding. Of course, you can still add a binding for the controller in case you need to specify more information for the binding (e.g. an additional constructor argument).
i found a similar questions, 
[How does Ninject create controller in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018810/how-does-ninject-create-controller-in-asp-net-mvc)
the answer saids:
Ninject finds constructor for this type, injects parameters, returns controller instance

my question is : if we don't register the controller how did the NinjectResolver resolve the controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

non-`abstract` classes (such as controllers) are resolved by ninject by default as `Bind<TheType>().ToSelf()` if there is no binding.