# ASP.NET MVC 4 Ninject MVC 4 Default constructor not found for type 'App.Controller'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, mono, ninject, ioc-container

I have set up a new ASP.NET MVC 4 Application in Xamarin Studio / monodevelop-opt on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Mono 3.10.0 mod-mono-server4 / xsp when running in IDE). Packages Installed are:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 4.0.40804
```

- Microsoft.AspNet.MVC
- Microsoft.AspNet.Razor
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages
- Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure

I also had to install Optimization Framework:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization
```

I chose to implement IoC container Ninject from NuGet and following packages were installed:

```
Install-Package Ninject.Mvc4
```

- Ninject
- Ninject.MVC4
- Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost
- Ninject.Web.Common

Because I installed Ninject.Mvc4, it created a nice file for me in App_Start called NinjectWebCommon.cs

Here is the Create Kernal Method:

```
    private static IKernel CreateKernel ()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel ();
        try {
            kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>> ().ToMethod (ctx => () => new Bootstrapper ().Kernel);
            kernel.Bind<IHttpModule> ().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule> ();

            RegisterServices (kernel);
            return kernel;
        } catch {
            kernel.Dispose ();
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Here is the Register Services Method:

```
    private static void RegisterServices (IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<IResourceEntryService> ().To<ResourceEntryService> ();

        var modules = new List<INinjectModule> {
            new ConfigModule (),
            new RepositoryModule (),
            new LoggingModule ()
        };

        kernel.Load (modules);
    }
```

Resource Entry Service and Interface:

```
public interface IResourceEntryService
{
    IEnumerable<ResourceEntry> GetResourceEntries ();

    IEnumerable<ResourceEntry> GetResourceEntriesByNameAndCulture (string name, string culture);
}

public class ResourceEntryService : IResourceEntryService
{
    IResourceEntryRepository _resourceEntryRepository;

    public ResourceEntryService (IResourceEntryRepository resourceEntryRepository)
    {
        _resourceEntryRepository = resourceEntryRepository;
    }

    #region IResourceEntryService implementation

    public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ResourceEntry> GetResourceEntries ()
    {
        IEnumerable<ResourceEntry> resourceEntries = _resourceEntryRepository.GetResourceEntries ();
        return resourceEntries;
    }

    public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ResourceEntry> GetResourceEntriesByNameAndCulture (string name, string culture)
    {
        IEnumerable<ResourceEntry> resourceEntries = _resourceEntryRepository.GetResourceEntriesByNameAndCulture (name, culture);
        return resourceEntries;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Controller for Resource Entry passing new model object into view:

```
public class ResourceEntryController : Controller
{
    IResourceEntryService _resourceEntryService;

    public ResourceEntryController (IResourceEntryService resourceEntryService)
    {
        _resourceEntryService = resourceEntryService;
    }

    public ActionResult Index ()
    {
        ResourceEntryViewModel viewModel = new ResourceEntryViewModel ();

        return View (viewModel);
    }
}
```

Here is my ~/Views/ResourceEntry/Index.cshtml file:

```
@model App.Web.UI.ViewModels.ResourceEntryViewModel

<h1>Resource Page</h1>
```

So now everything looks Okay right? Well wrong! I get the following error message when I try and view that page.

```
System.MissingMethodException
Default constructor not found for type App.Web.UI.Controllers.ResourceEntryController

at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, Boolean nonPublic) [0x00094] in /usr/src/packages/BUILD/mcs/class/corlib/System/Activator.cs:326 
at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type) [0x00000] in /usr/src/packages/BUILD/mcs/class/corlib/System/Activator.cs:222 
at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory+DefaultControllerActivator.Create (System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, System.Type controllerType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

Version Information: 3.10.0 (tarball Sat Oct 4 16:28:24 UTC 2014); ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.17020
Powered by Mono
```

Anyone have any ideas how to set up Ninject for MVC 4 application running on a mono stack.

I had a good google'ing and stackoverlow'ing and cant really find a definitive answer. Everything links to Web API, well im not really interested in Web API as I will be using ServiceStack if it comes to that.

I just want this Web application to work. Anyone have any suggestions?

**Update: 20/12/2014**

Runs fine under windows but not Ubuntu

I have created a simple application which can be found here:

[Sample Application](https://github.com/croconoster/MVC4_IoC)

Any Ideas?

**Update 21/12/2014**

I have tried another implementation of an IoC Container.

Same thing happens, I think this might be a Mono MVC 4 Thing. Still no idea why.

**Update 22/12/2014**

It looks like App_Start does not get invoked on start up.

I did a `Console.WriteLine` in the `CreateKernel` and in `RegisterServices` and nothing printed out.

I could get [SimpleInjector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleInjector.MVC3/) working by configuring the Container in the Global.ascx.cs file. It won't work if it gets initialized in the App_Start with the following line at the top.

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PostApplicationStartMethod (typeof(App.Web.UI.App_Start.SimpleInjectorInitializer), "Initialize")]
```

Wonder if there is a problem with WebActivator with Mono.

Comment: seems the ninject kernel is not correctly being registered as `IDependencyResolver`. Ninject does not (ever) throw a `MissingMethodException` with message "default constructor not found". Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018810/how-does-ninject-create-controller-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: This a mono-ninject framework issue? or did I miss something / need to add something else?

Comment: sorry i actually don't know. I'd look into how ninject.mvc registers the `IKernel` as `IDependencyResolver` and debug/check what's not working. I don't suppose it's a mono-specific issue but as said i don't know.

Comment: Yeh it's very strange, Im following the same architecture as the "Onion Architecture" which I found. The Demo project for that compiles and runs find on windows version of Xamarin.

Comment: If that demo project doesn't use ninject then it doesn't matter very much whether it runs fine or not...

Comment: Nope it does use it, well that is where I heard of Ninject. Might need to implement an alternative IoC container to get this working.

Comment: So the exact same example project is working under ms .net but not under mono? Do you have a link to the project?

Comment: Yup, correct. The link is updated in the question. It's a public project on github. https://github.com/croconoster/MVC4_IoC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the stack trace I can see DefaultControllerFactory down the bottom, which will instantiate the controller instance internally something like:

```
return Activator.CreateInstance(YourControllerType);
```

This call will get grumpy because your controller doesn't have a parameterless constructor, and you've not provided a list of parameter values for it to find an appropriate constructor to use... hence the exception.
Also, you don't want to provide the list of parameters, that would be inflexible and defeating the purpose of IoC, you want your IoC kernel instead to create the instance.

Now, I don't have experience with Ninject, so there maybe a more "Ninjecty" way of doing this (and if you know what that is please add to this :) but you need to create your own DefaultControllerFactory that can determine the type and use Ninject to create it.
Something like this:

```
// NOTE: Something like this, not exactly, I've not used Ninject!

public class YourControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    public override IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        var type = GetControllerType(requestContext, controllerName);

        return kernel.Get(type);
    }
}
```

Register it in Global.asax:

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new YourControllerFactory());
```

Now you have control over the instantiation process!